# Get all values of dictionary of lists

Tags: python, list, dictionary

```
l_d_l = {
'a' : [1,2,3]
'b' : [2,3,4,5]
'c' : [5,6]
'd' : [1]
}
```

I want to check if `1` exists in `a` in `l_d_l`. What's the best approach?

Comment: `import booleanChange from module`? You mean `from module import booleanChange`? Anyway the 2 *myBool* **are different**. You could have: `if booleanChange(): print("Hello world")`.

Comment: Couldn't you pass the reference to myBool as an argument in booleanChange()?

Comment: `myBool` is a local variable in the `booleanChange()` function. You can't access it outside the function. And even if you make it global, you need to import it from the module.

Comment: @AdamFeor Booleans are immutable, there are no references to them.

Answer (score 0):

Not only is the module a different scope, the function within is a different scope.  You have two variables names `myBool`; the one in `module` isn't even visible in the rest of the module.  If you want to have a module-level variable, you need to address is properly, such as:

```
# main

import module
module.myBool = False
booleanChange()
if module.myBool:
    print("Hello World")

# module
myBool = True      # Not needed, but illustrates the scope.
def booleanChange():
    global myBool
    myBool = True
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make `myBool` a global variable, and then import it.

module:

```
def booleanChange():
    global myBool
    myBool = True
```

main:

```
from module import booleanChange, myBool
myBool = False
booleanChange()
if myBool:
    print("Hello World")
```

Answer (score 0):

To just check for the value in the list do:

```
1 in l_d_l['a']
```